# jquery and native javascript simple DOM selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

This is my html code

```
<div class="class_test" id="id_test">
<h2>testing</h2>
<img/>
<div class="rightBox">
<h4>test</h4>
<p>test</p>
</div>
</div>
```

in javascript code, i want to select img to set it's **src , height , width**

```
$("#id_test > img").src = "blablabla.jpg";
$("#id_test > img").height = "100";
$("#id_test > img").width = "100";
```

but it doesn't work

Where did i miss it ?

Otherwise, how do i use the native javascript code without using jquery

```
document.getElementById("blabla")
```

i don't want to set the img ID

Comment: Are you sure that you set those properties (src, height, width) after the whole document is loaded?

Comment: yup, i sure about it ! because i load in jquery with ID tag succeessfully

Comment: `$("#id_test > img")` is array like object . to access first you should use this way `$("#id_test > img")[0].src` .. or use `attr` which loop items and set properties .. in behind it's iterate elements

Comment: i try [0] but it said Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Comment: @Huei try this ..`if ( $("#id_test > img").length > 0 ) { $("#id_test > img")[0].src = "blablabla.jpg" }` .. check length is greater than 0 .. if you not pass correct selector query . it's length is 0

Comment: @Huei: If you get that error, then `$` does not refer to jQuery. jQuery would *never* return `null`. If you want to use jQuery, make sure it's loaded.

Comment: I'm sure i have including jQuery because i used jQuery before this function !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xJ7gn/)

Width **jQuery**:

```
$("#id_test > img").prop('src','http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png');
$("#id_test > img").prop('height','100');
$("#id_test > img").prop('width','100');
```

Width **javascript**

```
var elm = document.getElementById('id_test');
var first = elm.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
first.src = "http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png";
first.style.height = '100px';
first.style.width = '100px';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#id_test > img").attr('src',"blablabla.jpg").attr('height',"100").attr('width',"100");
```

Comment: no =( it doesn't work, but trying $("#aaa") will success with ID tag

Answer (score 1):

I think that should work:

```
$('#id_test').find('img').attr({ 'src': 'blablabla.jpg', 'height': 100, 'width': 100});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery returns array like object .. eg : `$("#id_test > img")` returns the following array

```
[<img/>,<img />, ...]
```

For accessing it you can loop them using `for`, `while` .. or jQuery `each` method .

```
$("#id_test > img")[0] -> is Dom
```

Changing it will reflects into Dom .. But you should care `your selector` passing . If selector is not valid one .. `jQuery Object.length` is `0`

see difference between property and attribute on question [Properties and Attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)

```
var imgs =  $("#id_test > img");

// set first item ..    
if ( imgs.length > 0 ) {
    imgs[0].src = 'your src';

}

// set all items
if ( imgs.length > 0 ) {

    for ( var i= 0; i < imgs.length ; i++ ){
        imgs[i].src = 'your src'; // src is property
    } 
}
```

The best way is to use  [jQuery prop](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L383) method . Which set `src` property for all items , same like above `for loop` code .jQuery is safe for working on different browsers

```
imgs.prop('src','your src') // or pass json params
```

In hehind  loop each item ,... and set properties